# Loop interpretation

Tags: c++, ascii-art, interpretation

I'm having trouble in understanding some part of this code I've found online, its goal is to print ASCII art from a .txt file. To be more accurate, I'm having trouble in undesrstanding the while loop in line 28 which is part of the string function "getFileContents". What's the meaning of 'TempLine'?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <string>

std::string getFileContents (std::ifstream&);            //Gets file contents

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::ifstream Reader ("File1.txt");             //Open file

    std::string Art = getFileContents (Reader);       //Get file
    
    std::cout << Art << std::endl;               //Print it to the screen

    Reader.close ();                           //Close file

    return 0;
}

std::string getFileContents (std::ifstream& File)
{
    std::string Lines = "";        //All lines
    
    if (File)                      //Check if everything is good
    {
    while (File.good ())
    {
        std::string TempLine;                  //Temp line
        std::getline (File , TempLine);        //Get temp line
        TempLine += "\n";                      //Add newline character
        
        Lines += TempLine;                     //Add newline
    }
    return Lines;
    }
    else                           //Return error
    {
    return "ERROR File does not exist.";
    }
}
```

Comment: The meaning seems to be explained by the comments. What, ***specifically***, is unclear to you? P.S. like a lot of code that's "found online", it's buggy and has several logical flaws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), you can see that the string parameter is passed by non-const reference. This means that the string can (and is) edited by the `std::getline()` function. So line by line:

```
    // Loop until the file stream cannot read any more input.
    while (File.good ())
    {
        // Create a new, empty string called `TempLine`
        std::string TempLine;

        // Read a line from `File`, and write it into TempLine.
        std::getline (File , TempLine);

        // Add a newline character at the end of the string.
        TempLine += "\n";
        
        // Add the line we just read from the file to the `Lines` string,
        // which holds the full file contents.
        Lines += TempLine;                     //Add newline

    // Repeat until all lines have been read from the file (or the file
    // becomes otherwise unreadable).
    }
```

The reason `TempLine` is needed is because `std::getline()` needs something to read the file content into, and if we passed `Lines` directly to the function, we'd only ever return the last line of the file (the previous lines would always get overwritten in the string).